# sliding transitions not listening to each other in js

Tags: javascript

I have a js transition I can not resolve.  There are three links, blue/green/red, when you select one of the links a color swatch slides into the up position.  Push that same link again to make the color swatch slide into the down position.

How can I have each swatch slide all other swatches into the down position before sliding into the up position?

```
// When the DOM is ready, initialize the scripts.
jQuery(function( $ ){

// Get a reference to the container.
var container = $( ".container" );

// Bind the link to toggle the slide.
$( "a" ).click(
function( event ){
// Prevent the default event.
event.preventDefault();

// Toggle the slide based on its current visibility.
if (container.is( ":visible" )){

// Hide - slide up.
container.slideUp(500, function(){ $('').show(); });
} else {

// Show - slide down.
container.slideDown(500, function(){ $('').hide(); });
}
}
);

});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TuM5k/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked your jsfiddle with a simple solution: http://jsfiddle.net/cwmanning/jvj2u/2/

All in the fiddle, but it uses data attributes to switch classes instead of onClick attributes.

```
// Bind the link to toggle the slide.
$( "a" ).click(function( event ){
    // Prevent the default event.
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $target = $("#target");

    if ($target.attr("class") === $this.attr("data-color")) {
        container.slideUp(500);
    } else {
        // Hide - slide up.
        container.slideUp(500, function(){
            $target.attr("class", $this.attr("data-color"));
            // Show - slide down.
            container.slideDown(500);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The suggestion you gave me above would be ideal, but I need it to work within the if statement within the fiddle all the options will be src img, none will be data-color.  Your code would be ideal if you can modify it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick workaround. I am sure there is a much more elegant way, but seems to work.

just change the following:

```
function slider(v) {
    colors = {
        'blue':'blue2',
        'red' :'red2',
        'green':'green2'
    }
    var confirm = document.getElementById("target");
             if (colors.hasOwnProperty(v)){
                 setTimeout(function(){target.className = colors[v]},500);
              }else {target.className = "chart";}
 }
```

Substitute the following in place where you currently have the if(.... is(":visible").
I don't mean at the bottom of the code. Just sub the following in where it sits now in your code.

```
if (container.is( ":visible" )){
// Hide - slide up.
    container.slideUp(500,function(){$().hide()});
    setTimeout(function(){
        container.slideDown(500, function(){ $('').show(); })
    },500);

}else{
    container.slideDown(500,function(){$().hide()})

}
```

Comment: I added a new link for you to see what I am seeing on my side. [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/L8uee/1/)

Comment: That timeout can get really messed up if you start clicking a bunch at once. I almost had a solution then saw you posted this and gave up and exited out... Really regretting that now